# Find Pareto-optima two good economy

Tags: microeconomics, pareto-efficiency

There's an exercise I cannot wrap my head on. I actually have the solution to the problem, but still I don't quite understand it.

*Let an economy be composed of two consumers $A$ and $B$ and two goods $X$ and $Y$, such that $Y$ is produced using $X$ with production function $Y = \sqrt{5X}$. We suppose $A$ and $B$ have identical utility function $U(X,Y) = XY$. Initial endowment of the economy is $X = 1$ and $Y=0$ Find the Pareto-optima of this economy, and express them as a function of $X_A$, the quantity of good $X$ allocated to consumer $A$.*

So what I did to find those optima is to put $MRS_{XY}^A = MRS_{XY}^B$ subject to constrains $X_A + X_B \leq 1$ and $Y_A + Y_B = \sqrt{5(1 - X_A - X_B)}$. But it seems to me that I got to few equations to actually solve the problem. What I find is, putting $X = 1- X_A - X_B$:
\begin{align*}
Y_A = \frac{\sqrt{5X}}{1 - X} \cdot X_A 
\end{align*}
but I can't seem to be able to go any further... In the solution, it reads:
\begin{align*}
\frac{Y_A}{X_A} = \frac{Y_B}{X_B} (=\frac{Y_A + Y_B}{X_A + X_B}) = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{X}}
\end{align*}
without explaining how to derive the last equality.

Comment: in order to derive consumer's *A* demand for *x* one would need the initial endowment *of* consumer *A*; knowing the initial endowment of the whole economy tells us nothing about the initial endowments of the respective members of that economy; as the question stands it is unclear if we should contemplate a symmetric case or otherwise

Comment: @user43282 The question is about Pareto-efficient allocations, so the distribution of endowments between consumers is irrelevant.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist The question requests an answer in terms of *the quantity of good X demanded by consumer A* (please read the question again). I don't think we should try to replicate the supposed answer, but actually answer the question. As the question stands, it is incomplete.

Comment: @user43282 But the question is really asking about Pareto-efficient (PE) allocations, and demand functions are irrelevant to that problem. My best guess is that the entire question is just poorly stated -- what it is really asking about is the PE allocation as a function of the quantity of good $X$ allocated to consumer $A$, which is given by $X_A$. Under this interpretation, the supposed answer is indeed the correct one.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist you are making assumptions about the question; the question requests an answer in terms of the quantity demanded by consumer A; the question is poorly stated

Comment: @user43282 yes, but the question read that way makes no sense. The interpretation I propose is supported by the fact that nearly every exercise about PE allocations in a GE model is stated in that way, and the fact that the supposed answers are consistent with my interpretation.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist you are not answering the question itself but instead insist on interpreting the question and providing an answer to that interpretation; that is obviously your prerogative; I think that the question as it stands is deficient

Comment: @user43282 Oh, come on. Are there really any other plausible interpretations of the details of the question, given that the basic question is about characterising PE allocations? The rest of the question just states the form that the characterisation needs to take. Give me an alternate plausible interpretation and I will delete my answer.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist the question-not an interpretation of the question-requests an answer in terms of the **quantity of commodity X demanded by consumer A**; how does your answer encompass the **demanded** X of A?; please allow me to reiterate that the question is badly posed;

Comment: @Hermès I edited your question so that the way it’s stated matches the answer you’re looking for. Please let me know if you disagree with the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equality, as you've already found, equates $A$'s and $B$'s MRSs. The last equality comes from setting the marginal rate of transformation $MRT_{XY}$ between $X$ and $Y$ to the common MRS. For a production function with a single input and a single output, $MRT_{XY}$ is equal to $MP_X$, the marginal product of the input good $X$. That is:

$$ MRT_{XY} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt\frac{5}{X}. $$

For details, see Mas-Colell, Whinston and Green (1995), section 16.F.

Comment: you are providing the answer to a question *different* from the one asked

Comment: One of the OP’s questions is about the last equality, which I answer here. It should also go some way to answering the question about Pareto optimal allocations.